# Unit test Angular 5 - expect the Dialog to be closed

Tags: unit-testing, angular-material2, angular5

I have a component (which is a MatDialog component) whose one of the functions is simply to save some date and close itself on the end (the dialog), by simply calling "this.dialogRef.close(true);". So far so good.
The problem lies on the Unit test. When I try to test this function, Karma throws an error "TypeError: this.dialogRef.close is not a function". I suppose it does not recognise the function close which is called in the dialog, because I must have forgotten to initiat this dialogRef in my spec.ts file somehow, but I have no idea how to proceed, considering the fact that there are not so much material on the web about configuring Material 2 components in spec.ts. My question is: How to get this test to recognize this dialogRef.close() function by the unit test.

Some sample code below:
timeRangeDialogComponent.ts

```
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

export class TimeRangeDialogComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

 constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TimeRangeDialogComponent>,
           @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
 }

 saveCustomTimeRange(): void {
   this.dialogRef.close(true);
 }
}
```

TimeRangeDialogComponent.spec.ts

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ TimeRangeDialogComponent ],
    imports: [ FormsModule, MaterialModule, MatDatepickerModule ],
    providers: [
      { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} },
      { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: [] } ]
  })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TimeRangeDialogComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should call the function to close the dialog', () => {
  component.saveCustomTimeRange();
  expect(component.dialogRef.close()).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Error thrown: TypeError: this.dialogRef.close is not a function

I thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 17):

One way to fix it would be to supply a mock of the dialog class that has a close method instead of just supplying an empty object in your providers array. Something like:

```
// mock object with close method
const dialogMock = {
    close: () => { }
};

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ TimeRangeDialogComponent ],
    imports: [ FormsModule, MaterialModule, MatDatepickerModule ],
    providers: [
      { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: dialogMock },
      { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: [] } ]
  })
    .compileComponents();
}));
```

The close method here does not actually do anything but you can check to see if it has been called at least.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you don't have a spy setup for what you want to do.

```
spyOn(component.dialogRef, 'close');
```

Comment: Same result: "close is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

It's an open bug and solution with `ngZone`.  Try like this.

```
export class ErrorDialogService {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private ngZone: NgZone) {
  }

  openDialog(dialogData: DialogData): any {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.data = dialogData;
    let dialogRef;
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, dialogConfig);

    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
}
```

and dialog

```
export class ErrorDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  title = '';
  data: DialogData;

  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ErrorDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) dialogData: DialogData) {
    this.title = 'StarsWriters-Interceptor';
    this.data = dialogData;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  close() {
    console.log('CLOSE CLICKED'); // works
    this.dialogRef.close(true);   // Before running ErrorDialogService.openDialog without ngZone.run Fired but nothing happens. 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be simply done by adding spy on close method.

> The question contains error in the expect part as well, it is calling the close function instead it should be the reference [*close* instead of *close()*].

```
it('should call the function to close the dialog', () => {
  spyOn(component.dialogRef, "close");
  component.saveCustomTimeRange();
  expect(component.dialogRef.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for jasmine testing for dialog close

```
        const matDialogSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<MatDialogRef<any>> = jasmine.createSpyObj("MatDialogRef", ["open", "close"]);
    
    
        beforeEach(async () => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              declarations: [],
              providers: [
                MatDialogRef,
              ],
            }).overrideProvider(MatDialogRef, { useValue: matDialogSpy });
    
      it("should close dialog on click of close icon", () => {
     fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.member-access-close''))
    .nativeElement.click();
        expect(matDialogSpy.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
      })
```